# .lua are deleted when trying to copy nodemcu from one ESP8266 to another

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I'm trying to make a full memory dump of ESP8266 running nodemcu (with some .lua files) to make a copy of it. I'm using esptool.py for a dump. Like this: esptool.py.exe -p COM3 -b 230400 read_flash 0 0x200000 test.bin

When I look inside test.bin, I can see my lua code. So, those files are definitely there. But, when I upload this .bin to another ESP , nodemcu starts filesystem format procedure. Therefore, all .lua files are deleted. NodeMCU build itself seems to be fine.

Why does this happen if I make a full dump of the flash? Is there a register flag or something what defines that nodemcu should format filesystem? How can I copy ESP keeping all .lua files in place?

Comment: The Espressif SDK init data isn't part of the dump, right? That would indicate that the firmware runs on an new device in which case SPIFFS may be formatted. Some hints: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/flash/#sdk-init-data

Comment: Danke für einen Tipp! )

Answer (score 0):

Seems like NodeMCU was missing init data on 0x3fc000. 
So, the best way to solve an issue was to make a complete memory dump. 
`esptool.py.exe -p COM3 -b 230400 read_flash 0 0x400000 test.bin` in my case.